# Search for tags incl. wildcard (*) and additional search parameters

Tags: support, tags, search, elasticsearch

Does the new search engine also support searching for tags incl. wildcard and additional search parameters, like

```
[silverlight*] is:question
```

Currently this results in an empty list.

I expected it to work like the auto-favorite feature when i add a tag with an additional * to favorite all tags that match that pattern.

([tag:prism*] ->[prism](/questions/tagged/prism) or [prism-4](/questions/tagged/prism-4) or [prism-2](/questions/tagged/prism-2))

**NOTE:** 
I know that i can omit the `is:question` parameter to get all questions in this case, cause [silverlight*] would be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to work for me! [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsilverlight*%5D%20is:question)!

<sub>It might have something to do with the build that just went out, maybe.</sub>

Comment: Uhhhh nice. Seems to work.

Comment: @Jehof - I've been meaning to get wildcard support in for a while, just didn't get to it until this morning.  They also work in an `or` chain with other tags and such.

Comment: The PS given by you is absolutely correct. I tried to search [on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstatus*%5D+is%3Aquestion) when this question was bumped but didn't work at that time.

Comment: works really nice. small note: when searching for more tags (such [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23-*%5D+%5Bwpf*%5D+is%3Aq) there s(c)hould be an `or` between `c#-code-model` and `wpf` in the tagged with section

Comment: @Jehof - that's not an `OR` search...you have to explicitly put an " or " between them if you want posts tagged by *any* of those...current your search requires *one tag from each wildcard* to be a result.  [See that much higher result count here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23-*%5D+or+%5Bwpf*%5D+is%3Aq)

Comment: ok, right. With "or" its right. What search have i done with my query?

Comment: @Jehof - The post has to have one of each wildcard in your search so (A or B or C) *and* (D or E or F).  This is the same as a normal `[A] [B]` search being an *and*, it must meet all conditions and a wildcard is a single condition (they can't work any other way...nothing is tagged with more than 5, so an *and* wildcard makes no sense).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Now i understand how the search works.

Comment: @NickCraver - Doesn't this question require a tag `Status-Completed`?

Answer (score 0):

It only works on it's own,

```
[silverlight*]
```

But not as part of a larger query

```
[silverlight*] is:question
```

Comment: It is because if we type only tag name in search box, it redirects us to [`/tagged`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql*) page instead of [`/search`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql*%5D+is%3Aquestion) page.