# Advanced Search Tips should also mention about the use of wildcard

Tags: feature-request, search, wildcards, tips

On the [search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) page, **Advanced Search Tips** should also include the **wildcard** usage which are valid for both [tags searches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171641/search-for-tags-incl-wildcard-and-additional-search-parameters) and word searches. Wildcard is mentioned against the "url" search but it does not clear up the usage because in url search "*" is used inside quotes which does not work for regular word searches.