# Add tips for Search by Range to the Advanced Search Tips

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

It is not obvious to users that one can enhance searches using [Google number range style](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?p=adv_operators&hl=en).  I had to find this information out through [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188781/give-us-better-search-by-score-syntax).  Enhance the Advanced Search Tips to note the basic syntax for search by range; there is enough vertical space for it.

Relevant text paraphrased from [Nick Craver's source answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188781/give-us-better-search-by-score-syntax%20/188786#188786) in Advanced Search Tips style:

```
range:     score:..2 (<= 2)
           score:-2.. (>= -2)
           score:-2..2 (>= -2 and <= 2)
           score:2..2 (2)
```

Sibling questions:

- [Add tips about Date Range and Code Searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166835/can-we-update-the-search-tips-to-include-all-available-operators)
- [Add tip about using Wildcard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184888/advanced-search-tips-should-also-mention-about-the-use-of-wildcard)

Comment: Also, you better believe I'm "score:-5.. answers:0" for a Reversal badge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a whole help article dedicated to this now, already available here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching

That help article will also be linked at the bottom of the advanced search tips when expanded after the next build rolls out.  We can put a lot more detail into the article than the sidebar.  If you see something missing or inaccurate, definitely suggest changes and we'll make it better.

Comment: There are probably several questions you'll need to `status-completed`, I think.  :-)