# Search word division is unintuitive

Tags: bug, search

I had to resort to Google to find an answer I wrote on Stack Overflow. I searched for [`user:me XmlLanguage`](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A573420+XmlLanguage). When I finally found the answer, it turns out that `XmlLanguage` only occurs as part of a fully qualified name, so a search for `user:me *XmlLanguage` would have found it, but (a) I didn't know about the wildcard, which [isn't mentioned in the "Advanced Search" help tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184888/164922); and more importantly (b) I thought I was searching for a whole word, so it didn't occur to me to look for help on searching for partial words.

I can't see any reason for the search to consider alphanumeric strings separated by `.` to be part of the same word. IMO it's a bug that U+002E (`.`) isn't considered just as much a word separator as U+0020().

Comment: The advanced search help wasn't updated for years, while they upgraded their search engine at least twice in those years, resulting in many things that are now likely not documented anywhere. :(