# Search with user operator missing results

Tags: support, search

I would like to search for this post of mine:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345132#67346760

So I try these:

```
user:1002260 IndexString
user:1002260 code:IndexString
```

but I just get this result:

```
We couldn't find anything for indexstring
Search options: user 1002260
Try different or less specific keywords.
```

Why can't I search my own posts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The term `IndexString` occurs as a part of the longer string `m.IndexString("foo` in [the post you're searching for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345132#67346760).

For this reason, you need to use wildcards `*` to find this post.
Indeed, when I try searching for `user:1002260 *IndexString*`, I see your post in the [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1002260+%2AIndexString%2A). Searching for `user:1002260 *IndexString` also [works](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1002260+*IndexString).

Perhaps this has to do with the fact that `.` is not taken to be a word separator. Related posts pointed out by Tinkeringbell in the comments: [Search word division is unintuitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320489/986753), [What about an upgrade to the word delimiter list for a more accurate search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100656/986753).